# Autotools: If I only change the installation directory do I need to rebuild everything? If not how can I avoid this

Tags: makefile, build, autotools

I build a `C++` code with autotools i.e. `./configure && make && make install`, but now I want to change the directory where the code installs so I should do `./configure --prefix=${INSTALL_DIR} && make && make install`.
Does this now recompile the whole code (I would like to avoid this at all cost) and if so are there other options?

I have heard about the `export DESTDIR="${INSTALL_DIR}" && make install` trick, but I have also heard that this keeps somehow the reference to the install directory and as well a relative path in the binary. So far I have not found a good explanation of the difference of the two approaches anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot tell you any of the answers to these questions because they all depend 100% on your project and how it's configured.  Did you actually try to run the above commands?  What happened?  That's for more useful information, and much more readily available, than asking *us* what will happen.

In most autoconf projects `./configure` will create a header file `config.h` which contains the configuration, and in most projects that header is included by all the source files, so modifying that file will indeed cause everything to be rebuilt.

In most autoconf projects, the `config.h` file won't be updated (and so nothing will be rebuilt) unless its contents change.

In some autoconf projects the prefix directory is provided as a `#define` in the `config.h` file, and so in those autoconf projects if you change the value of `--prefix` then `config.h` will be updated and all the code will be rebuilt.

Whether your project falls with in the category of "most" and "some" above, only you can say.

As for the difference between `--prefix` and `DESTDIR`, you've already discovered it: the value of `--prefix` is set at configure time and could be (depending on the project) compiled into the code itself as a hardcoded path (but this is generally considered not desirable: projects should either use relative paths or, where not possible, provide some environment variable or option to reset this path).

`DESTDIR` is not available at compile time, and is an install-time setting that only changes where the makefiles will copy files to, without changing any compiled-in paths that were set by `--prefix`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually helps! so if my `config.h` would be unchanged I would not need to compile everything from scratch

Comment: It's worth noting that you can override the installation prefix at `make` time by specifying `prefix=/my/other/prefix` on the `make` command line.  This is usually more appropriate than using `DESTDIR` (which has a rather specific purpose), and it can do some things that `DESTDIR` cannot.  A well designed Autotools build system will accommodate that properly, but not all projects have well-designed build systems in this sense.

Comment: @krabbypatty yes, assuming the system is set up according to best practices.  Not all are.  I'm still not sure why you're asking us what will happen, instead of just trying it and seeing what actually happens.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes although note that if the prefix is in the code, resetting it on the make command line won't change it.  Agreed that `DESTDIR` is intended for a specific purpose: staging the install for further packaging, such as in an RPM or DEB or else with something like GNU stow.  Whether it works for "standard" installs as well depends on the particular package.